# Reading a messed up Text File using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am new to PIG and Big Data. I just came across a scenario: Data from an Excel file was copied into a simple text file resulting into chaos. So now, we need to filter/refine the data of text file using PIG script. Can we even do that? If we can, how can we sort the data into well formatted file?

A sample is,

```
InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country
536365  85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER  6   2010-12-01 8:26 2.55    17850   United Kingdom
536365  71053   WHITE METAL LANTERN 6   2010-12-01 8:26 3.39    17850   United Kingdom
```

Like this we have multiple records in text file.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What chaos? Isn't it a tab delimited file?

Comment: Though we have spaces between records, but the rows of excel file are stored as simultaneous data in Text file. The first row of excel, containing headers is stored as a first line in text file and then, right after it we have value of first row of excel.

Comment: This is order not chaos.It can't be more well formatted than this.The file can be loaded easily by ignoring the first line in the file and then transform and extract the fields required.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind: thanks for reply mate! So I can just pick up any data from text file without any issue? For instance, WHITE METAL LANTERN which comes under the Description, (and more like it), can be picked up/analysed upon using PIG or HIVE?

Comment: Yes,you would load the file and use FILTER on description column

Comment: In "WHITE METAL LANTERN" space is the delimiter, If you are reading the contents of the file using tab (\t) as delimiter you should not be seeing any issues.